# Remove &nbsp; from html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to remove `&nbsp;` from the below code.

```
<div class="country-IN">
   <span class="locality">Barnala</span>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <span class="state">Punjab</span>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <span class="country">India</span>
</div>
```

Please help me to get out of it.

Comment: remove it how? Can't you just open the file and hit delete?

Comment: This may be a code snippet stored in a CMS...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.country-IN');
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8aL3J/).

Or, with jQuery:

```
$('.country-IN').html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8aL3J/1/).

Or even:

```
$('.country-IN').children().each(function(i,e){
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this.nextSibling);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8aL3J/2/).

Though it'd be easier to simply edit the HTML files themselves and just *remove* those strings of characters.

Comment: You left off the semicolon here: should read `/&nbsp;/g` as in your JS Fiddle demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the elements you want and add it back as the html for the element

```
$('.country-IN').html(function(i,v){
   return $('<div>').append($(this).children('*')).html(); 
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y5Ly8/)

Answer (score 0):

Library agnostic:

```
(function() {
var country_els = document.querySelectorAll('.country-IN');

for (var i = 0; i < country_els.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < country_els[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = country_els[i].childNodes[j];
        if (typeof node.tagName === 'undefined') {
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        }
    }  
}
})();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VmeGJ/)

Answer (score 0):

First, get your whole HTML div and convert it to the string

```
convertHtmlToText(str)
{
   str = str.toString();
  return str.replace(/<[^>]*(>|$)|&nbsp;|&zwnj;|&raquo;|&laquo;|&gt;/g, ' ');
}
```

you will get the text without HTML tag and &nbsp etc

you can add multiple conditions in the above solution

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to javascript for that. We can hide the `&nbsp;` with only CSS. Add `font-size: 0` to container and `font-size: 1rem` to child.

```css
.second {
  font-size: 0;
}

.second > span {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="country-IN">
  <span class="locality">Barnala</span>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="state">Punjab</span>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="country">India</span>
</div>

<div class="country-IN second">
  <span class="locality">Barnala</span>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="state">Punjab</span>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="country">India</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with preg_replace in PHP.

```
<?php
$html = "YOUR HTML"
$new = preg_replace("!&nbsp;!", "", $html);
print($new);
?>
```

I used this script before and it should work fine.