# How can I remove content like &nbsp; from an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` where the content looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    &nbsp;
    <div class="eventSpot bg-blue"></div>
    <div class="eventSpot bg-blue"></div>
    <div class="eventSpot bg-red"></div>
</div>
```

The `&nbsp;` is causing some styling problems so I need to remove it.

How can I remove just that part of the content with jQuery/javascript?

Comment: Why can't you remove it in html code itself ?

Comment: Do you only want to remove the `&nbsp;` or _any_ non-tag-contents (if you know what I mean ;))

Comment: It's not put there by me, it's inserted in by a third party plugin. So I need to remove it after the page is rendered

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345631/remove-nbsp-from-html

Comment: How do you define “just that part”? Do you mean any NO-BREAK SPACE in the content, or just a single one in a particular context (exactly which?)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
var div = $('div.container');
div.html(div.html().replace(/^\s*&nbsp;/m, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer working with nodes instead of html as a string if possible, so I would suggest something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/p7v89/

```
$('.container').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).remove();
```

That will find all text nodes and remove them.

Answer (score 1):

you will get the text without HTML tag and &nbsp etc

This is a solution for HTML tag and &nbsp etc and you can remove and add conditions

```
convertHtmlToText(passHtmlBlock)
{
   str = str.toString();
  return str.replace(/<[^>]*(>|$)|&nbsp;|&zwnj;|&raquo;|&laquo;|&gt;/g, ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively try the [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method.

```
var $data = $('.container > div').detach();
$('.container').empty().html($data);
```