# Hiding &nbsp; with CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to hide `&nbsp;` with CSS?

I have value like `AMBASSADOR&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(1982.03 - 1984.10)`

And I want all `&nbsp;` to be represented as one regular space;

It's for `<select>` options to display something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmxnQ.png

Comment: can't you alter your html?

Comment: Altering text nodes via CSS? I'm afraid that it is not possible.

Comment: As mentioned above I don't think this is possible with CSS. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345631/remove-nbsp-from-html) is a related question with other methods.

Comment: I don't think there is a CSS way to do it. maybe you cane use javascript to do it

Comment: Hiding something is different from representing it as a space. If the last sentence tells what you actually want, you should edit the title and the first sentence to match it. (The answer is still “No”.)

Comment: Why are you using `&nbsp;` over and over. If you are simply trying to position text you should be using CSS to do so.

Comment: @ChristianJuth I want to space out `<select>` list elements into columns by indenting them with whitespace.

Comment: That is a bad way to do it. You should be using CSS to style it. That is what CSS if for. You can imagine HTML as the skeleton. The way I look at it `&nbsp;` is more of a hack and should be avoided. The reason HTML only interprets one space is because if it did not it would count your returns and spaces you use to keep your HTML readable. `&nbsp;` is forcing HTML to interpret that space.

Comment: @ChristianJuth OK, please answer how you want to do it with CSS respecting crossbrowser (IE 7 and up) & crossystem (MacOS, iOS, Windows and Android devices, touch as well) complaints in `<select>`: http://i.imgur.com/v3xPqMh.png

Comment: I would be happy to build a working example but to do so I would need you to show more of your code or a picture of your end goal.

Comment: @ChristianJuth you've got screenshot of desired output in previous comment what else do you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide just certain pieces of text with CSS.  `&nbsp` is a rendered character, just like the letter `G` or `X` is.  You can't select certain letters with CSS, so this really can't be done as it is currently.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Chris Barr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79677/chris-barr) said, you won't be able to fix this with CSS as we don't have any character selector.

The last option I see on the frontend side is to use a bit of javascript to cleanup the text. The dom node will not contain literal `&nbsp;` strings so you'll have to use `String.fromCharCode(160)` to find and replace them.

Yes, this is not with CSS.

```js
const span = document.getElementById('fixMe');

const replacement = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(160), 'g')

span.innerText = span.innerText.replace(replacement, " ");
```

```html
<span id="fixMe"> AMBASSADOR&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(1982.03 - 1984.10)
</span>
```