# replace &nbsp; with some other text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck in a thing where I need to replace `&nbsp;` with some other text.

I have tried the following code.

```js
var text = $("#nbspData").text().replace('&nbsp;','a');
$("#removedData").html(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="nbspData">this&nbsp;is&nbsp;me.</p>
<p id="removedData"></p>
```

But when I inspect the code the `&nbsp;` is not removed.

Comment: check out the solution from another post [Remove &nbsp; from html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345631/remove-nbsp-from-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) doesn't returns those encoded chars, it just returns the text you're seeing, e.g.: "this is me". So there is nothing to replace. Change `text()` to [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
var text = $("#nbspData").html().replace('&nbsp;','a');
```

```js
var text = $("#nbspData").html().replace('&nbsp;','a');
$("#removedData").html(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="nbspData">this&nbsp;is&nbsp;me.</p>
<p id="removedData"></p>
```

Additional info: Use a regex replace if you want to replace all occurences of `&nbsp;`:

```js
var text = $("#nbspData").html().replace(/\&nbsp;/g,'a');
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="nbspData">this&nbsp;is&nbsp;me.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for HTML tag and &nbsp etc and you can remove and add conditions
based on your reuirement

```
convertHtmlToText(passHtmlBlock)
{
   str = str.toString();
  return str.replace(/<[^>]*(>|$)|&nbsp;|&zwnj;|&raquo;|&laquo;|&gt;/g, 'replaceWithAnyText');
}
```